# C# compiler issues a compile error when implementing == and != operators record definitions

Tags: c#, c#-9.0

I have a record per the following example:

```cs
public record MyData
{
   public string Id { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   
   public bool operator ==(MyData d1, MyData d2)
   {
      return d1.Id == d2.Id;
   }

   public bool operator !=(MyData d1, MyData d2)
   {
      return d1.Id != d2.Id;
   }
}
```

This is the error message that I get and I'm not sure how to resolve it!

> error CS0111: Type 'MyData' already defines a member called
> 'op_Equality' with the same parameter types.

When I convert `record` to `class` this issue is resolved but due to some reasons we have to keep using `record`. What's the solution to get rid of this compile problem?

Comment: Records already define the `==` and `!=` operators to call the `Equals` method. Instead, you should define a `public virtual bool Equals(MyData other)` method (and also override `GetHashCode`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is by design according to [specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-9#value-equality):

> For records, the compiler generates the Equals method. In practice, the implementation of value equality in records is measurably faster

> In class types, you could manually override equality methods and operators to achieve value equality, but developing and testing that code would be time-consuming and error-prone. Having this functionality built-in prevents bugs that would result from forgetting to update custom override code when properties or fields are added or changed.

That means that you should consider performance benefits in comparison to `struct` types which have the same equality semantics but have their own disadvantages, for example, in terms of boxing.

Tho if you want to have your own equality logic working with the operators, you could add `public virtual bool Equals(T)` and `public override int GetHashCode()`. The compiler generated equality operators are calling `virtual bool Equals(T)` inside, which is autogenerated and uses value equality if not overrided by the developer.

Comment: -1. It is absolutely fine to override equality in records -- the language design team have repeatedly said that this is what you should do if you want to customise equality. The point here is that you need to specify the `Equals(MyData other)` method, not the `==` operator

Comment: @canton7 why would you want to use `records` and customise equality then? Any real world use cases? What's the benefit of records then and why not use class or struct in the first place?

Comment: You get: 1) primary constructors, 2) withers, 3) automatic `ToString`

Comment: @canton7 sounds reasonable, tho we don't know why OP decided to use `records` in the first place, I was assuming performance benefits and less error prone practices. Updated my answer according to your comment.